# How to change V and F in constant V/F control of an ACIM?

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, three-phase, induction-motor

If I generate 3-Phase PWM outputs to drive a 3-phase ACIM and use constant V/F method for speed control then how will I change V and F of the generated PWM outputs?

I will generate PWM's using LUT method. What I understand is that by changing the PWM duty cycle sinusoidally I can generate the PWM but how to change its voltage? and Frequency?

Comment: [Pulse width modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) - what is it that you don't understand about this article in relationship to changing V and F?

Comment: Let us say the line voltage is 380V, 50Hz and I want to generate 200V, 25Hz. How will I generate a sine wave of 200V as my switching of the outputs is on 600V DC Link bus?

Comment: Sinewave peak amplitudes are wholly dependent on the maximum and minimum PWM duty cycle AND the bus voltage.